# How to compare Edit Text with Room Database Text

Tags: android, android-studio, viewmodel, dao

I'm new to Android Studio.

I'm trying to create a login page where the user needs to write the email address and the database will compare that inputted email address with the one it has in the database.

I'm using view model to deal with any data-related task. I'm using coroutine to access the database so the app won't crash.

My problem is that, if I use `loginViewModel.checkEmailAddress().toString()` it will only show it as `kotlin.Unit` which isn't what I want, I want to show `user@mail.com` and that email address is already in the database on its own.

When the user writes the correct email address and after clicking on the button, it will go to the next fragment. So far, it fails because the database always return as `kotlin.Unit`.

Here's the fragment:

```
class Login : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: LoginBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater, R.layout.login, container, false
        )

        val arguments = LoginArgs.fromBundle(requireArguments())
        val application = requireNotNull(this.activity).application
        val dataSource = ArchelonDatabase.getInstance(application).userDao
        val viewModelFactory = LoginViewModelFactory(arguments.surveyKey, dataSource, application)

        val loginViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(LoginViewModel::class.java)

        binding.loginViewModel = loginViewModel

        binding.lifecycleOwner = this

        binding.loginBtn.setOnClickListener {
            if (binding.email.text.toString() == loginViewModel.checkEmailAddress().toString()) {
                this.findNavController().navigate(
                    LoginDirections.actionLoginToMenuSelection()
                )
            } else {
                val message = "Nope"
                Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
        return binding.root
    }
}
```

Here's the View Model:

```
class LoginViewModel(
    val database: UserDao,
    application: Application
) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    fun checkEmailAddress(
    ) {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main.immediate).launch {
            checkEmail()
        }
    }

    private suspend fun checkEmail(): String {
        return database.getEmailAddress()
    }
}
```

And here's the DAO:

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {
    // Update existing row if it's using the same ID
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insert(user: User)

    @Query("SELECT email_address FROM user_table LIMIT 1")
    suspend fun getEmailAddress() : String

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your ViewModel**

```
    private lateinit var _userEmailAdress = MutableLiveData<String>()
        val userEmailAdress : LiveData<String>
        get() = _userEmailAdress
        
        fun checkEmailAddress(
                ) {
                    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main.immediate).launch {
                        val userEmail = checkEmail()
                        _userEmailAdress.value = userEmail
        
                    }
                }
```

**Your Fragment**

```
binding.loginBtn.setOnClickListener {

   loginViewModel.checkEmailAddress()
   loginViewModel.userEmailAdress.observer(viewLifecyleOwner,{
   if(it == binding.email.text.toString()){
   // your logic code
}
})
```

Your problem is that the function is returning a String value and trying to get a return using coroutine. I tried to prepare an exemplary concept on mobile.

Comment: Thank you. That works, my next issue is the navigation. If the user pass on the wrong email address, the toast message appears but when they put the correct email address the app crash. However, if the user pass the correct information for the first time, it does not crash.